# Partition/count rows up to condition, then group the remainder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have a table as such:

```
| RowID|  Date_id   | Diff
| -----+------------+-----
|  78  | 2010-07-17 | 1
|  80  | 2010-07-18 | 1
|  81  | 2010-07-19 | 1
|  82  | 2010-07-20 | 1
|  83  | 2012-05-22 | 670
|  84  | 2012-05-23 | 1
|  85  | 2012-05-24 | 1
--
| 300  | 2012-12-24 | 1
| 301  | 2012-12-25 | 1
| 302  | 2012-12-26 | 1
```

What we're trying to do is count the number of rows until the diff is greater than 183. If that the number of rows is greater than 100 then all the rows in that set is marked 'Y' else 'N'

There is the possibility that there are multiple junctures or no junctures at all, in which case the entire set is one big group.

Results we're looking for:

```
| RowID|  Date_id   | Diff | 100
| -----+------------+------+-----
|  78  | 2010-07-17 | 1    | N
|  80  | 2010-07-18 | 1    | N
|  81  | 2010-07-19 | 1    | N
|  82  | 2010-07-20 | 1    | N
|  83  | 2012-05-22 | 670  | Y
|  84  | 2012-05-23 | 1    | Y
|  85  | 2012-05-24 | 1    | Y
--
| 300  | 2012-12-24 | 1    | Y
| 301  | 2012-12-25 | 1    | Y
| 302  | 2012-12-26 | 1    | Y
```

After trying to see if I can partition by a condition, and see if window functions or while loops might be the answer, I'm no further.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the rows **always** ordered by `RowID` (or `Date_id`)?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Hi yes, every row is order by RowID, which is itself in date order. from earliest to latest.
It is always ordered

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2019

Comment: @Ticho how did you get on?

Answer (score 1):

1. Categorise your rows into groups using a windowed sum function
2. Count the rows in each group using a windowed count function and use a case expression to display the desired value
3. I've used 4 rather than 100 to demonstrate

```
declare @Test table (RowID int, Date_Id date, Diff int);

insert into @Test (RowID, Date_id, Diff)
values
(1, '2010-07-17', 1),
(2, '2010-07-18', 1),
(3, '2010-07-19', 1),
(4, '2010-07-20', 1),
(5, '2012-05-22', 670),
(6, '2012-05-23', 1),
(7, '2012-05-24', 1),
(8, '2012-12-24', 1),
(9, '2012-12-25', 1),
(10, '2012-12-26', 450);

declare @MinRowsRequired int = 4; -- Change to 100

with cte as (
  select *
    , sum(case when Diff > 183 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by RowID asc) GroupNum
  from @Test
)
select RowId, Date_Id, Diff
  --, GroupNum -- Uncomment to see how it works
  , case when count(*) over (partition by GroupNum) > @MinRowsRequired then 'Y' else 'N' end [100]
from cte
order by RowID;
```

Returns:

| RowID | Date_id | Diff | 100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-07-17 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 2010-07-18 | 1 | N |
| 3 | 2010-07-19 | 1 | N |
| 4 | 2010-07-20 | 1 | N |
| 5 | 2012-05-22 | 670 | Y |
| 6 | 2012-05-23 | 1 | Y |
| 7 | 2012-05-24 | 1 | Y |
| 8 | 2012-12-24 | 1 | Y |
| 9 | 2012-12-25 | 1 | Y |
| 10 | 2012-12-26 | 450 | N |

Note: Providing sample data as DDL+DML as shown here makes it much easier for people to answer

Comment: Thank You for the quick response, I will bear your note in mind in the future! Thanks again

Comment: Did it solve your problem?